# Take & remove elements from collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, time-complexity

What's the most performant way to remove n elements from a collection and add those removed n elements to an already existing, different, collection?

Currently I've got this:

```
var entries = collection.Take(5).ToList();
foreach(var entry in entries)
    collection.Remove(entry);
otherCollection.AddRange(entries);
```

However, this doesn't look performant at all to me (*multiple* linear algorithms instead of only one).

A possible solution may of course change the collection implementation - as long as the following requirements are met:

- `otherCollection` must implement `IEnumerable<T>`, it is currently of type `List<T>`
- `collection` must implement `ICollection<T>`, it is currently of type `LinkedList<T>`

Hint: entries do not necessarily implement `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()`.

What's the most performant way to reach my goal?

---

As it has been obviously too hard to understand my performance considerations, here once more my code example:

```
var entries = collection.Take(1000).ToList(); // 1000 steps
foreach(var entry in entries) // 1000 * 1 steps (as Remove finds the element always immediately at the beginning)
    collection.Remove(entry);
otherCollection.AddRange(entries); // another 1000 steps
```

= 3000 steps in total => I want to reduce it to a single 1000 steps.

Comment: You always have a linear search with a O(n) operation, there is nothing better with a collection.

Comment: I think the collection has a RemoveAll(collection.Take(5))

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It's not about collection or non-linear search. It's about how to avoid *multiple* O(n) operations. See my code sample!

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Which collection? Currently typeof(collection) is LinkedList which *does not* support `RemoveAll()`

Comment: Performant isn't a word.

Comment: @spender: Please feel free to edit my post, English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: @D.R. I don't think there is any way to avoid doing multiple O(n) operations. The extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` were intentionally designed that way.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Even that must search through the whole collection to see which elements match a given predicate. It's just more elegant, no more, no less.

Comment: @D.R. Your English is fine. I suspect that "performant" is a new word in the making, because it's used in almost 5000 questions/answers here on SO. Carry on...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: However, a RemoveAll would only need to go through the underlying list *once*, my approach does it entries.Count() times. May bad: I don't know any collection which supports RemoveAll...

Comment: @D.R.: If you know that you want to take 5, why don't you use [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414.aspx) instead? No additional search required.

Comment: So otherCollection implements IEnumerable.  IEnumerable does not support AddRange.  What exactly are the collections and are you limited to those collections?

Comment: @Blam: No, `otherCollection` is not of type `IEnumerable`, it just needs to implement `IEnumerable`! Currentlycollection=LinkedList<T> and otherCollection=List<T>, however I'm not limited to those at all - as long as my requirements are fulfilled (see initial post).

Comment: @D.R.: Btw, you don't understand LINQ's deferred execution. `collection.Take(1000)` does not need to iterate 1000 times. The `foreach` enumerates it and the `AddRange`, so 2000   instead of 3000 steps.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot ToList() - otherwise we would have a possible duplicate enumeration.

Comment: What about, if you're doing `.ToList()` you can use the `RemoveRange(index, count)`

Comment: Need to count more than steps.  An O(1) step is not the same as an O(n) step.  AddRange is n + m if capacity must be increased so increase the capacity first.  There is more to consider than number of steps.  Are the steps of minimum Order?  RemoveRange is O(n).  Other than increasing the capacity before the AddRange don't think you are going to do better.  Are you having performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your use case the best data structure seems to be a queue. When using a queue your method can look this this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAndRemove<T>(Queue<T> queue, int count)
{
   count = Math.Min(queue.Count, count);
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      yield return queue.Dequeue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous function only returns half results. You should use:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAndRemove<T>(Queue<T> queue, int count)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < count && queue.Count > 0; i++)
      yield return queue.Dequeue();
}
```